# Summing an associative array based on key value

Tags: php, arrays, associative-array

I have an associative array fetched from mysql, and I need to sum values based on the value in a different column. I have created an associative array, and printed to screen and it looks okay. It returns what I need, and looks like `[1] => 779700.00 ) Array ( [4] => 868.00 ) Array ( [2] => 102000.00 ) Array ( [2] => 775808.00`

My problem is that I need to be able to sum the results for each individual key value pair (so eg '2' would sum to 877808.00) - there are only eight key values, and I need a variable to hold each one. I have read lots of similar questions and have tried the solutions, but have just got myself hopelessly confused.

I assume I need a foreach loop, please could somebody point me in the right direction for what I need to do?

```
while($row_outputs=mysqli_fetch_array($run_projects))
                { 

                $Id = $row_outputs['id']; 
                $impact = $row_outputs['impact']; 
                $cost = $row_outputs['total_cost']; 

                $summing_array = array($impact=>$cost);
```

Answer (score 0):

I would make a new array to hold the the results from your sums and then for every row check if you already have an entry for that $impact in the results array. If not create it, if so, add the $cost to it. This can be done like so:

```
    $results = [];
    while ($row_outputs = mysqli_fetch_array($run_projects)) {

        $Id = $row_outputs['id'];
        $impact = $row_outputs['impact'];
        $cost = $row_outputs['total_cost'];

        if(isset($results[$impact])){
            $results[$impact] += $cost;
        }else{
            $results[$impact] = $cost;
        }
    }
```